# Edit view not displaying model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I've bumped into a situation where my Edit view is not displaying data passed through the model from my controller. While debugging I can clearly see that the model contains data. Also this is something that was working before and stopped without warning, it may be linked to other changes I have made in my code but I am unaware of their relation.

I have tried to completely remove the edit view and create a fresh one but the issue persists.

Here is a snippet of my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label         col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "CategoryId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller that calls the view:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    ViewBag.IssueId = id;
    _issue = _context.Issues.Find(id);
    _issue.Users = _context.Users.ToList();

    var firstOrDefault = _issue.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == _issue.CreatedBy);
    if (firstOrDefault != null)
        ViewBag.CreatedName = firstOrDefault.FullName;

    _issue.IssueTexts = _context.IssueTexts.Where(i => i.IssueId == id).ToList();

    if (_issue == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    PopulateDropDownLists();

    return View(_issue);
}
```

As I said it was working before then broke without warning so I am not certain which direction to start looking in. If this trivial for some of you, I apologize for my naivety in advance. Any assistance would be great.

Comment: You said that the model contains data. Did you put a break point in the view to verify this, or just in the controller's action?

Comment: @DanielGabriel I had only done so on the controller. I put one on the view and the model contains nothing. What happened?

Comment: If you are displaying your view as a partial, you should make sure that you are passing the model as a parameter, like this: `@Html.Partial("view name", Model)`

Comment: @DanielGabriel thanks for the reply. If I'm understanding correctly, the Edit view is not partial, it does however use the login partial view that is handled in the layout view. Does this make a difference? And as I mentioned, it was working before without me needing to do any of that.

Comment: @DanielGabriel just to add to my earlier comment, the model itself is not = null. The values of everything inside the model is null as though I had only passed it over as a new instance of "Issue".

Comment: @DanielGabriel thank you, I found what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was the method PopulateDropDownLists() was instantiating _issue object again. I had a problem earlier where inside the method _issue was null and I instantiated it without checking if its null first.

Pardon the rookie move. Thank you.

Comment: I also suggest you study all of your code carefully. This code inside `if (_issue == null)` can never be executed. After setting the value of `_issue`, the next line sets its `Users` property. If `_issue` was null, that would throw an exception!

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you for the heads up. @StephenMuecke